# determine user-modified files

Tags: filesystems, files, backup

I plan to reinstall my operating system since I messed up some stuff. Access to files and folders is painfully slow sometimes, even if they contain just a few files.

But of course, I don't want to do *everything* again. I remember adding a few aliases for `ssh` to make my daily work more convenient, I changed some syntax-highlighting files for `gedit` and probably a lot more than I currently remember.

Is there a way to easily see which **files** were **modified by a specific user**? Alternatively, is there a way to find files, not found in a fresh installation? Backing up the stuff in the home directory is easy, but I don't want to search through every single directory just to remember "Oh, I put something there as well".

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu, but this should be distribution independent, shouldn't it?

Comment: @stefan Package management is one of the major differences between distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily look for files that **belong** to a specific user:

```
find -xdev / -user bob
```

Unix doesn't keep track of who modified a file.

There is no easy way to locate system files that you've changed. The normal way to maintain a unix system is to let the OS manage its own files and put your own files in separate directories. On Linux, the convention is that

- `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/lib` and `/usr` outside `/usr/local` belongs solely to the distribution;
- `/usr/local` belongs solely to the system administrator;
- `/etc` is populated by the distribution but may be modified by the distribution.

Your home directory, of course, belongs to you.

When you do things like adding aliases for ssh or syntax highlighting files for Gedit, do it in `/usr/local` if you want them to be available to all users, or in your home directory otherwise.

If you really need to change something under `/usr` because an application only looks for files there and not under `/usr/local`, put the actual file under `/usr/local` and make a symbolic link under `/usr`.

To keep track of files that you've changed in `/etc`, I recommend [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/). All good distributions  (including) offer it. (If your distribution doesn't, take this as a commentary on your distribution.)

You can go and look for files that have been modified from the distribution-provided versions. This is different for every package manager. Since you mention Ubuntu, the low-level package management tool is [dpkg](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html). For each package, there is a list of files with their checksums in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGENAMES.md5sums`. You can compare the list with what you have installed on your system.

```
sort /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums >/tmp/packaged.md5sums
cd /
find bin etc lib sbin usr -path usr/local -prune -o -exec md5sum {} + | sort >/tmp/actual.md5sums
comm -23 /tmp/actual.md5sums /tmp/packages.md5sums
```

Answer (score 0):

> I remember adding a few aliases for ssh to make my daily work more convenient, I changed some syntax-highlighting files for gedit and probably a lot more than I currently remember.

If I understand your question correctly, isn't this the entire point of the `/home` directory structure? Almost all per-user configurations that you have made will most likely be found in your home folder. For `gedit` for example, I would bet that there is a folder called `.gedit` in your home folder containing individual configurations for that software.

You might not want to restore your entire home folder, but at least if you back it up you can add these things in manually later, as in when you discover your gedit configuration is gone, just close gedit and copy in your old `.gedit` folder -- and so on.

For historical record keeping of changes to your text files, you might want something like [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/).

Comment: As I've written in the question: It's not about the home directory. E.g. I have a custom script placed in /usr/sbin/ for convenience (that might be stupid, I don't know, but it happened). It's about "what files did I touch?".

Comment: Another example: The style file for gedit resides in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/`. That's far from `/home/` and easily missed

Comment: I know this is completely unhelpful, but I would say that 1) You should have a symlink in `/usr/sbin` and not the actual script (hindsight is always 20/20), and 2) I'm not familiar with how gedit does things but I would say that it arguably makes more sense to store the styles of users *in their home folders* (both `vim` and `irssi` does this to my knowledge). Again, not helpful to blame the authors.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you may wish to preserve the existing installation,
and to do a fresh install into currently unused disk space
(or back up to a separate (external?) disk, and reinstall.)

Once the fresh install is complete, then mount the old install
on (say) /old (or each of the file-systems from the old install,
on (say) /old/root , /old/usr , /old/home, etc.) and then use 
"diff -r / /old" to help identify files present in /old that are
not present in the fresh install in / .  Expect lots of 
false positives from differing versions of installed software.
Minimize those by trying to install exactly the same setup
(distro, OS version, package selection).  This is not an 
easy approach, but should be exhaustive - and perhaps exhausting.
Good luck.